# Image manipulation with pure CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've the following image

```html
<div class="product-main-img">
    <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" alt="@Model.Name" />
</div>
```

This image could be bigger than its container or smaller than it. When smaller I need to center it vertically and horizontally but if it's bigger, I need to contain it and center the shorter side.

I can do this, each on its own, and see which styling I need to apply using JavaScript; but I kind of want to solve it using pure CSS. Any idea?

Comment: The first thing that crosses my mind is to use calc ( ) for the width and height. Otherwise, the usual "margin: auto" or "table/table-cell" trickery for vertical/horizontal centering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes the container has specified dimensions (*since you mention that the `img` might be bigger/smaller*).

So use flex for the container (*which allows centering its child element*) add `min-width` and `max-height` to the image.

```css
.product-main-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.product-main-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-main-img">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x100" alt="@Model.Name" />
</div>

<div class="product-main-img">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x200" alt="@Model.Name" />
</div>

<div class="product-main-img">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100" alt="@Model.Name" />
</div>

<div class="product-main-img">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x200" alt="@Model.Name" />
</div>
```

Comment: was just writing a comment about the maxwidth/height, i want to upvote it but not enough reputation, great job.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way of doing this is to set the image as the `background-image` of the `<div>`, then use `background-position: center` and `background-size: contain` to make it fit to the container. For example:

```css
.image-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"
    style="background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/1/)"
></div>

<br>

<div class="image-container"
    style="background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/200/400/cats/1/)"
></div>
```

Comment: This will fail. though, on the "*When smaller I need to center it*" as it will center it but will also scale it up as much as possible (*without cropping*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ooh, good point. I don't know as there's any way to avoid that without flexbox.

Comment: there are a few tricks if the container has fixed height/width. For example the image be `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` and then the container has `text-align:center` and `line-height:<same-as-height>`. Another using `table-cell` and another with absolute positioning and transform for centering.